# Django : Deduce duplicate key exception from IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-models, psycopg2

With Django 1.6, I get an exception when there's a duplicate key

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "..."
```

Django uses `IntegrityError` exception for other types of database violations too. I want to handle the `duplicate key` as a special case i.e.

```
try:
    model = MyModel(name='xyz')
    model.save()
except MyModal.IntegrityError:
    if exception_due_to_duplicate_key:
        do_something()
except:
    do_something_else()
```

Is there a unique error code for that or will I have to parse the error message. I'm trying to avoid `get` call to database to ascertain that violation is due to a duplicate key.

**Update**: I should mention that exception is thrown by `psycopg2` since I'm using Django with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Perhaps `get_or_create` also catch your requirements.

Comment: Django >= 1.6 now provides a `__cause__` for `IntegrityError`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError

Comment: @danihp : Won't that defeat the purpose of trying to avoid `get`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the comment from @karthikr, I found the error type:

```
type(e.__cause__)
<class 'psycopg2.IntegrityError'>
```

A little poking around showed this:

```
e.__cause__.pgcode
'23505'
```

My understanding is, as long as I stick with the same database I can check this to verify that it's a duplicate key error.

<strike>& `psycopg2` doesn't change the error code,</strike>

Comment: The error code comes from postgres and it shouldn't change: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html